# Proving $L=\{wvw|v\in \{0,1\}^*, w\in \{0,1\}^+\}$ is not regular using the myhill-nerode and pumping lemma

Tags: pumping-lemma

Firstly, I've tried assuming $L$ is regular and find a contradiction with help of the pumping lemma's 3 conditions, I was not able to get to a contradiction.

I've tried thinking of a word $z\in \{0,1\}^*$ to attach to $wv^i$ and $wv^j$ for some $i\neq j$, and to combine that with the pumping lemma's $xy^2z\in L,  k\geq 1$ yet I got stuck on the way.

I'm looking for a direction of thought, a colleague suggested looking at the example word $10000000110000000$ , yet I cant see the how this example promotes what I'm trying to prove.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Determine if this language is regular](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/14159/determine-if-this-language-is-regular) The language is slightly different, but the accepted answer seems to apply. (And is similar to what your colleague suggested.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This language is regular. Denote $L = \{wvw\mid v,w\in\{0,1\}^*\}$.

I claim $L = \{0,1\}^*$. Indeed, the inclusion $\subseteq$ is clear. Conversely, let $u\in \{0,1\}^*$. Then $u = \varepsilon u\varepsilon \in L$.

Comment: Apologizes, I've forgot to mention the fact that $\epsilon \notin L$
I've also saw how it is regular when $\epsilon \in L$.

Comment: What you say makes no sense: the language $\{wvw\mid v,w\in\{0,1\}^*\}$ is uniquely defined and it contains $\varepsilon$.

Comment: Even if you consider $L = \{wvw\mid v,w\in\{0,1\}^*\}\setminus\{\varepsilon\}$, it is still regular, because regular languages are closed under set difference.

Comment: double apologizes, it was my misunderstanding of the instructions I was given.

 after further clarifications from my instructor, instead of $\epsilon \notin L$, what I've meant is that the $w$ in $w,v\in \{0,1\}^*$ satisfies $w\neq \epsilon $

Comment: Then just write $L = \{wvw\mid v\in \{0,1\}^*, w\in \{0,1\}^+\}$ so that there is no ambiguity.

Comment: I see, I can also understand this notation. Thank you for this clarification.

Answer (score -1):

Of course it is regular, because it contains the complete set {0,1}*.

Note: This was the correct answer to the question before it was edited.